# Проблема при использовании JNI и библиотеки Speex

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Подключал  библиотеку  по [туториалу](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1726) . Вроде бы все подключилось, теперь я хочу написать свой метод который вызывает  нативный код который в свою очередь потом должен будет вызывать функции из библиотекии. Кода я хочу создать метод для вызова нативного кода с помощью "подсказок" AndroidStudio то сразу создается файл  который обведен  красным.

в Java

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("speex");
}

private native void initEncoder();
```

в С

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
                  Java_com_audiorecorderclient_MainActivity_initEncoder(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    // TODO

}
```

и при вызове функции `initEncoder();`  ловлю

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.audiorecorderclient.MainActivity.initEncoder() (tried Java_com_audiorecorderclient_MainActivity_initEncoder and Java_com_audiorecorderclient_MainActivity_initEncoder__)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libspeex
LOCAL_CFLAGS = -DFIXED_POINT -DUSE_KISS_FFT -DEXPORT="" -UHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  \
./libspeex/bits.c \
./libspeex/buffer.c \
./libspeex/cb_search.c \
./libspeex/exc_10_16_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_10_32_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_20_32_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_5_256_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_5_64_table.c \
./libspeex/exc_8_128_table.c \
./libspeex/fftwrap.c \
./libspeex/filterbank.c \
./libspeex/filters.c \
./libspeex/gain_table.c \
./libspeex/gain_table_lbr.c \
./libspeex/hexc_10_32_table.c \
./libspeex/hexc_table.c \
./libspeex/high_lsp_tables.c \
./libspeex/jitter.c \
./libspeex/kiss_fft.c \
./libspeex/kiss_fftr.c \
./libspeex/lpc.c \
./libspeex/lsp.c \
./libspeex/lsp_tables_nb.c \
./libspeex/ltp.c \
./libspeex/mdf.c \
./libspeex/modes.c \
./libspeex/modes_wb.c \
./libspeex/nb_celp.c \
./libspeex/preprocess.c \
./libspeex/quant_lsp.c \
./libspeex/resample.c \
./libspeex/sb_celp.c \
./libspeex/scal.c \
./libspeex/smallft.c \
./libspeex/speex.c \
./libspeex/speex_callbacks.c \
./libspeex/speex_header.c \
./libspeex/stereo.c \
./libspeex/vbr.c \
./libspeex/vq.c \
./libspeex/window.c \
./wrapper.c


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Он может не видеть библиотеку, в gradle файле есть следующие строки:

        ndk {
            moduleName "speex"
        }
    ?

Comment: Нету, я их убрал, с ними не получалось подключить либу, ошибки выдавало

Comment: @AdamLuisSean  вот с таким сообщением ошибка #error You now need to define either FIXED_POINT or FLOATING_POINT